# If $0<a, b, c, d<1$, then how do I prove the following inequality $(a+b+c+d+1)^{2} \geq 4\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

An interesting problem, I kind of solved it, but I'm not sure that I solved it correctly. Different solutions are welcome.

**My attempt:**

Let $x=a+b+c+d$ and $y=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2} .$ We easily see that $0<x<4$ and $0<y<x$. Thus it suffices to prove that $(x+1)^{2} \geq 4 x>4 y$. Conveniently, $(x+1)^{2}-4 x=x^{2}+1+2 x-4 x=x^{2}+1-2 x=(x-1)^{2} \geq 0$